Databricks: How to obtain Text based on HashKey
We have defined a User defined Function as follows:
def hashIt(key):
    key=key.upper()
    hashKey = H.md5(key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return hashKey

udf_hashIt = F.udf(hashIt, T.BinaryType())
spark.udf.register("HashtUDF", udf_hashIt)

Now as part of the DataFrame, we are using:
df=df.withColumn('HashText', F.concat_ws('|', *bkp_col_list)) 
df=df.withColumn('HashKey', udf_hashIt('HashText')) 

and later drop the HashText, but keep the HashKey and save it into a Delta Table
However based on the HashKey, Is there a way to obtain the HashText back.
Need the HashText from HashKey

to clarify, are you asking to retrieve the input to a hash function from the hash result?  If so that's not generally possible, you need to store both.

To obtain the HashText back from the HashKey, you can use a join operation between the original DataFrame and the Delta Table that contains the HashKey.
The UDF defined and registered the UDF HashUDF and used it to create a HashKey column.
I have tried the below approach:
import hashlib
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, BinaryType
def hashIt(key):
    key = key.upper()
    hashKey = hashlib.md5(key.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return hashKey
udf_hashIt = F.udf(hashIt, StringType())
spark.udf.register("HashUDF", udf_hashIt)
data = [("John Doe", 25), ("Jane Smith", 30), ("Bob Johnson", 35)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "Age"])
df = df.withColumn("HashText", F.concat_ws("|", "Name", "Age"))
df = df.withColumn("HashKey", udf_hashIt("HashText"))
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/FileStore/tables/delta_table")
delta_df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/FileStore/tables/delta_table")
hash_text_df = delta_df.select("HashText", "HashKey")
hash_text_df.show()

Results:
+--------------+--------------------+
|      HashText|             HashKey|
+--------------+--------------------+
|Bob Johnson|35|6482eb6af25b91ee9...|
| Jane Smith|30|687d685e316f35604...|
|   John Doe|25|636468cf1942a6989...|
+--------------+--------------------+

In the above code wrapping the hashIt function in a PySpark UDF called udf_hashIt with a return type of StringType.
Registering this UDF as HashUDF in the Spark SQL context.
Concatenating the Name and Age columns with a | separator and stores the result in a new column HashText.
Using the udf_hashIt to compute the hash of the HashText column and store it in a new column HashKey.
Next, Writing the DataFrame df to a Delta table
